# Is there a way to see the history of changes made to a question or an answer?

Tags: support, edits

I have seen this a few times.

Scenario 1:

1. user1 asks a question.
2. user2 answers the question.
3. Somebody adds some comments to the question that seem useful -> leads the OP to change the question.
4. Answer in (2) does not make sense any more.

Scenario 2:

1. user1 answers a question.
2. user2 adds comments to the answer indicating why the answer is incorrect or how it can be improved.
3. user1 agrees with user2, goes ahead and makes changes to the answer.
4. Now comments from user2 don't make sense any more.

In both these cases, it will be nice to be able to view the history of the question (in Scenario 1) and the answer (Scenario 2).

Is there a way to see the history of changes made to a question or an answer?

Comment: I'm sorely tempted to post an answer that's completely unrelated only to claim that you edited this question into something entirely different.

Comment: [Yes, posts do have a revision history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/253012/revisions)

Comment: Another fun scenario is when there's been a back and forth in the comments and I delete my comments because they are obsolete. Whoever was responding to me looks like they are imagining a conversation.

Comment: @Louis Yeah, that has happened to me too.

Comment: @j08691 I have started using SO extensively over the last 2+ months even though I joined 3+ years ago. Forgive me for not knowing what is possibly a simple method.

Comment: Thanks to @Servy's comment, I got it. Couldn't find a direct link to it from a post but I know how to get there.

Comment: There's also [the timeline view](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/), e.g., http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/253012/timeline

Comment: Given the high volume of traffic why does this only have 657 views at the time of writing? Can it be made more accessible so people don't make accidental duplicates like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377200/how-can-i-check-my-facts-before-posting-a-question-about-a-specific-question

Comment: @BruceAdams,  I guess not many people ask such questions or looking for answers to such questions :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Thanks to @Servy's comment, I got it. Couldn't find a direct link to it from a post but I know how to get there

The revisions to question whose URL is `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253012/...` can be found at `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/253012/revisions`.

The timeline view can be found at `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/253012/timeline`.

Comment: 4+ years and I never knew about timeline view either!

Comment: Is there a way to request that these URLs be linked to from the post page?

Comment: A small point but it had me scratching for a little while:  The revision URL for a question at `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345678/some-question` is `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12345678/revisions`, timeline is at `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12345678/timeline`.  If you do what I did - i.e. put the `.meta` in as well - you get a page not found error.

Comment: Great thing about timeline, it shows the close / reopen history.

Answer (score 25):

perhaps the layout has changed since this question was first asked, but there is a time-stamped link to the revision history on every question and answer that has been edited above the last editor's user name/card (which is blank if it's been edited by the original poster).

[image: link to post revision history]

however, I have yet to find a link to the timeline. so based on [**@R Sahu**'s answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253012/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-history-of-changes-made-to-a-question-or-an-answer#253019), I wrote this short [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) to view the current page's question's timeline:

```
javascript:(function() {window.location.href=window.location.href.substring(0,window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")).replace("questions","posts")+"/timeline"})()
```

now I've got this saved to my browser's bookmark toolbar so I can easily view the question timeline at the push of a button. this has not been extensively tested, so feel free to propose edits.

Comment: You didn't have to delete your previous answer Jeff, you could've just edited it. :)

Comment: lol I didn't think that one through all the way. I just deleted it at first because of your insight. then I realized that was a totally new answer, so I posted it. finally I had an afterthought for the timeline, so I just edited the 2nd answer with another version of the bookmarklet for revisions

Comment: +1 for that Bookmarklet.  Very useful

Comment: Would be nice if we could promote this answer to "best answer" status, since noone is realistically expected to remember to append "/revisions" to the URL.

Comment: BTW, the timeline is currently linked by the "clock/refresh" icon below the link to 'bookmark this question' and the voting buttons.