# See edits made to my answers

Tags: support, edits, search

Is there a way to see which edits were made to all my answers/questions so far?

Someone suggested an edit on my answer, if it was someone else's answer I'd reject it as "Please add a comment instead" but since it was for my own answer I thought I'd let others decide. Then saw that the edit was accepted.

Anyway, which raised the question for me that is there a way to see which edits were accepted/rejected on all my answers/questions?
Or at least for a specific answer, just having the link to the question.

I saw [Is there a way to see the history of changes made to a question or an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253012/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-history-of-changes-made-to-a-question-or-an-answer) but trying that link with the ID of the question I answered to gave a page not found. I don't know if there's a way to find the ID of my answer which that link will work with.

Comment: Especially since it's your own answer you should decide. In fact, you get final decision on edits to your own stuff. If you would have rejected it on someone else's post, reject it on yours.

Comment: You can only find the timeline for the question, answers are part of the timeline: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26761857/timeline

Comment: @rene Thanks. I don't know how you figured which question I was talking about but that's a useful link which I didn't know existed. So I guess there's no way to find out all edits on all my answers/questions so far? I saw some search page link here the other day, can't remember it now but I thought maybe that search page would have something like what I asked. i.e. userid= myid&type=edits.. etc

Comment: I looked at your profile, clicked answers, sorted by activity. The first answer was edited 22 hours ago so it was not much of a gamble...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the suggested edits for your posts in SEDE in [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/244847/all-suggested-edits-for-a-user?UserId=3309109)

```
select p.id as [Post Link]
, s.owneruserid as [User Link]
, s.id as [Suggested Edit Link]
, s.comment
, s.creationdate
, s.approvaldate
, s.rejectiondate
, vt.name
, v.userid as [User Link]
from posts p
inner join suggestededits s on s.postid = p.id
inner join suggestededitvotes v on v.suggestededitid = s.id
inner join votetypes vt on vt.id =  v.votetypeid
where p.owneruserid = ##userid##
and p.posttypeid in (1, 2) -- question, answer
```

The timeline url only works for posts that are questions. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26761857/timeline) links to the question that has your answer which was edited 22 hours ago. The [`/timeline`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post) url is not officially supported.