# What should I consider before posting a question about a specific question?

Tags: support, meta, faq-proposed

[Questions about questions are allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377197/are-questions-about-specific-questions-off-topic-on-meta-stackoverlow/377199#377199) but waste bandwidth if not well considered.

How can I check my question before posting on meta?

Comment: This looks an awful lot like [Is there a way to see the history of changes made to a question or an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253012/215552)....

Comment: You are right. It is essentially a duplicate as the answer is the timeline feature in both cases. I was aiming for something more FAQ like in reaction to failing to find a relevant FAQ myself.

Comment: I reopened your question. I'm sure there's more to this than simply perusing the timeline. The answer you've provided is a decent start.

Comment: @BoltClock Should this be changed to a feature request rather than a support? If I understand the tags better now. Support is when the question is intended to request support from the community. This question is now intended to provide support instead.

Comment: The [support] tag can be used for both purposes. This isn't a request for a feature so FR is inappropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO has several useful but not well advertised features for this (they are required to support the meta site).
There are URLs for:

- edits made to a question
- a timeline of activity relating to a question
- votes relating to events on the timeline (for example there is an automatic vote to reopen a question after it is edited)

You can review the timeline using a URL like:

- stackoverflow.com/posts/*{postId}*/timeline

You can view the edits using a URL like:

- stackoverflow.com/posts/*{postId}*/revisions

There is also a quick link to the edit history:
[image: the revision history is available via the edited indicator]

The timeline will show you if there were any important events like reviews.
You can look at the votes for reviews using URLs like:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/*{reviewId}*   &
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/*{post}*/votes

which will be linked to from the timeline.
For example this post is:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/377200/timeline

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/377200/revisions

Also note that questions about specific questions should be given the [specific-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specific-question) tag.

Once you reach 1,000 reputation, you can click on the total vote score
displayed by any post to break the score down into the actual vote
counts, given as the number of upvotes and downvotes.

[image: click to expand votes]

There are a few other things to be aware of:

- Users below 10K cannot see deleted posts
  If you are asking a question about a post people cannot see beware that people may act based entirely on the timeline information which they **can** see.

  Adding a screenshot might be one way to work around this.
- Asking why my question was deleted is not the same as asking what is wrong with my question. 
  See [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/377194/1) for example. The user intended it to look like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377207/why-is-this-question-about-magic-comments-in-go-still-considered-off-topic) but many users actually read it like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/377194/8)
- Meta posts may attract more attention than you are used to on regular SO.

  Not everyone knows an obscure technically subject well enough to comment but a lot more people feel able and willing to judge a question.

See also:

- [FAQ for how to access question's timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125170/faq-for-how-to-access-questions-timeline)
- [Is there a way to see the history of changes made to a question or an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253012/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-history-of-changes-made-to-a-question-or-an-answer)

From which this answer copies